# Can websocket latency be monitored/recorded with javascript?

Tags: javascript, websocket, google-chrome-devtools

There are plenty of ways to monitor ajax request latency, render/paint times, etc., but I can't figure out how to record the same metrics for websocket performance.

Is there an easy way to hook into a request and measure it's performance with javascript?

Comment: What exactly do you want to measure?  Can you modify client and server in order to add the ability to measure this?

Comment: @jfriend00 I'm using Firebase, and their SDK connects via websockets to their server. I want to monitor how that's performing over time by measuring latency and the amount of time it takes to send over a data (measured by the start and end frames). I can't modify the SDK, so I'm looking for native browser hooks.